# Php Calculation

Tags: php

I am making a simple order page the user will select an ammount on 1 page then on the next page it runs this

```
<?php
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
$sum= $bar * 1.59;
echo "Your price". $sum; 
?>
```

the only problem we are having with this is that if they enter a certain ammount say 10 so for example 10 * 1.59 = 15.90 but it only shows 15.9 for any others it will show the ammount fully e.g for 5 it would show £7.95 - Is there something i could change in the code for it to always show the xx.xx figure instead of xx.x

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
echo sprintf("Your price %.2f", $sum);
?>
```

Comment: Just to note that Daniel's solution, when dealing with money, is probably a better way to go.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 8):

I think that this is exactly what you're looking for: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
...
echo "Your price: " . money_format("%.2n", $sum);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use PHP function number_format.

```
<?php echo "Your price". number_format(number, 2, '.', '')); ?
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php